# How to use vectorization instead of for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization

I'm trying to build a machine learning algorithm for my job. The data I'm using for training and testing has 17k rows and 20 columns. I've tried adding a new column based on two other columns but the for loop that I've written is too slow (3 seconds to be executed)

```
for i in range(0, len(model_olculeri)):
    if (model_olculeri["Bel"][i] != 0) and (model_olculeri["Basen"][i] != 0):
        sum_column = (model_olculeri["Bel"][i]) / (model_olculeri["Basen"][i])
        model_olculeri["Waist to Hip Ratio"][i] = sum_column
```

I read articles about pandas and numpy vectorization instead of for loop on pandas dataframes and it seems like it is so much faster and effective. How can I implement this kind of vectorization for my for loop? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, looping over each row is generally slow, especially if you have an operation (in this case, division) that you want to apply on an entire column.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean mask and use it for filtering:

```
m = (model_olculeri["Bel"] != 0) & (model_olculeri["Basen"] != 0)
model_olculeri.loc[m,"Waist to Hip Ratio"] = model_olculeri.loc[m, "Bel"] / model_olculeri.loc[m,"Basen"]
```

Alternative:

```
model_olculeri.loc[m,"Waist to Hip Ratio"] = model_olculeri["Bel"] / model_olculeri["Basen"]
```

Or set new value in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
model_olculeri["Waist to Hip Ratio"] = np.where(m, model_olculeri["Bel"] / model_olculeri["Basen"], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Chained solution using `query` and `pipe`

```
model_olculeri.query("Bel != 0 & Basen != 0").pipe(lambda x:x.assign(Waist to Hip Ratio =  x.Bel/x.Basen)
```